# Deliver a message from google cloud functions to virtual machine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

currently I automatically start a VM after running a cloud function via this code:

def start_vm(context, event):

```
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
result = compute.instances().start(project='PROJECT', zone='ZONE', instance='NAME').execute()
```

Now I am looking for a way to deliver a message or a parameter at the same time. After the VM starts and based on the added message/parameter, a different code runs. Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Appreciate every help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Guest attributes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/manage-guest-attributes). The Cloud Functions add the guest attribute and then run the VM.

In the startup script, you read the data in the guest attributes and then you use them to perform stuff.

---

The other solution is to start a webserver in the VM and then to POST a request to this webserver.

This solution is better is you have several task to perform on the VM. But, take care of the security is you expose a webserver. Expose it only internally and use a VPC connector on your Cloud Function to reach your VM.